# json library interprets space characters as "\xa0"

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

When I load a json-file into python there's no problem with encodings as long as the file is treated as a string. However, loading the file into json-format either using json.load on the file or json.loads on the string all space characters come out as "\xa0"

The following code yields normal results, printing the json-string without any funky "\xa0" signs.

```
with open(json_path) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```

Loading the file into json-format and suddently space characters are interpreted as "\xa0".

```
with open(json_path) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data.keys())
```

gives the following:

> dict_keys(['1.\xa0\lorem\xa0ipsum', '2.\xa0\lorem\xa0ipsum\xa0\lorem\xa0ipsum', '3.\xa0\lorem', '4.\xa0\lorem\xa0ipsum', '5.\xa0\lorem\xa0ipsum'])

Loading the string instead of the file using json.loads gives the same results:

```
with open(json_path) as f:
    lines = f.read()

data = json.loads(s)
print(data.keys())
```

I'm building a pdf-parser using java and pdf-box. Parsing the headline structure into my own json-tree. I've tried converting the json-file into Hashmap in java, which works fine so there doesn't seem to be anything weird about the json-file in itself. Is this a python-specific problem and is there any explanation for it?

Comment: Nothing to do with JSON. \x escapes aren't legal in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

1. Your JSON file is valid and uses UTF-8 as the encoding.
2. Your JSON file contains keys with non-breaking spaces.

Then the output you get is perfectly correct.

The first piece of code reads and print strings:

```
with open(json_path) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```

When you *print* a string, it is output more or less unchanged and the non-breaking spaces look the same as a regular space.

The second piece of code parses a JSON file thereby creating a dictionary and then prints the dictionary keys. For simplicity of explanation, let's assume the dictionary itself is printed (instead of the keys):

```
with open(json_path) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)
```

Calling *print* with a dictionary as an argument invokes the `__str__` function of the dictionary. The `__str__` function uses it's own rules how to format the output, e.g. it encloses the dictionary in braces, adds single quotes etc.

If you study the output you might find that *printing a dictionary creates valid Python code for a dictionary*.

In Python strings, certain characters need to be escaped. And the escape sequence starts with a backslash. A typical example would be a newline character:

```
d = {'line1\nline2': 3}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'line1\nline2': 3}
```

Part of `__str__` dictionary logic obviously is to also escape non-breaking spaces as they otherwise cannot be visually distinguished from a regular space (even though this is not strictly necessary). And the proper way to escape it in Python is `\a0`.

So everything works as designed. It's a feature, not a bug.