# How to set character encoding for PDFBox

Tags: java, parsing, encoding, pdfbox, iso-8859-1

I'm bulding a pdf-parser using [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/), after parsing the plain text i run some algorithms and in the end output a json-file. For some pdf files the output file contains utf-8 encoding, for other pdfs it contains some form of what seems to be latin-1 encoding (spaces show up as "\xa0" when the json-file is opened in python). I assume this must be a consequence of the fonts or some other characteristic of the pdf?

My code to read the plain text is as follows

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

//Instantiate PDFTextStripper class
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

//Retrieving text from PDF document
String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);

//Closing the document
document.close();
```

I've tried just saving the plain text:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outPath + ".txt");
out.print(text);
```

Even opening this plain text file in python yields "\xa0" characters instead of space if the file is read into a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) , yielding the following results:

> dict_keys(['1.\xa0\lorem\xa0ipsum', '2.\xa0\lorem\xa0ipsum\xa0\lorem\xa0ipsum', '3.\xa0\lorem', '4.\xa0\lorem\xa0ipsum', '5.\xa0\lorem\xa0ipsum'])

I'd like to make sure the text always gets encoded as utf-8. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: It seems you're mixing up things here: The *String* type in Java is independent of any encoding. So assuming the value of *text* is ok, the encoding only depends on how you process the variable and output it to a file. It's completely unrelated to PDFBox. So check if the value of *text* is ok: if so ask another questions showing your output code. If not, modify this question to *Why is PDFBox unable to properly parse the text" and add the specific PDF example.

Comment: I've made some edits explaining the specific issue I encounter. I assumed the string has some bad encoding since I assume just saving it to file wouldn't change anything

Comment: Run the code in the debugger and check the value of *text*. Both *PrintWriter* and Python apply some possibly invalid encoding. So to many unknowns to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: BTW: 0xa0 in iso-8859-1 is the *non-breaking space*. So you might just be expecting the wrong thing.

Comment: yes I know "\xa0" is the non breaking space, I just don't understand why it gets encoded in iso-8859-1 (latin-1). The only solution I can find to this problem is replacing the "\xa0" characters in python, but that doesn't go to the root of the problem.

Comment: *PrintWriter(String filename)* uses the default charset (aka encoding). What is your default charset in Java?

Comment: String defaultCharacterEncoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding"); yields UTF-8 when I run it so I assume its UTF-8. Like I said I only encounter the problem with some pdf:s so it should be related to some property of the actual pdf that PDFBox interprets.

Comment: If your default Java encoding is UTF-8, then your file is encoded in UTF-8. Looks like your Python code or they way you output the data from Python is the problem. Your current setup is: 1) read PDF, 2) output to text file, 3) read text file, 4) output read text. These are four steps with text encodings involved, four places to introduce a problem. Simplify your setup. Otherwise you won't be able to locate the problem.

Comment: I've described the python code in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406800/json-library-interprets-space-characters-as-xa0?noredirect=1#comment95673158_54406800. I can't for the world of me figure out what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to make sure the text always gets encoded as utf-8. How do I go about doing this?

If you want to make sure your `PrintWriter` uses UTF-8 encoding, say so in the constructor:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outPath + ".txt", "UTF-8");
```